# Solve $y\,\mathrm{d}x + (3+3x-y)\,\mathrm{d}y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am trying to solve an ODE problem: $y\,\mathrm{d}x + (3+3x-y)\,\mathrm{d}y=0$ and I am stuck. My instinct told me to treat it as an integrating factor problem by the partials don't match. I tried doing substitution letting $v= y/x$ but it does not become separable. What can I do?

Comment: Find an integrating factor of the form $\mu(y)$. You will then get an exact equation.

Comment: So I don't understand because I thought in order to do that I needed to have it in the form y' +P(x)y=Q(x).

Comment: You may want to read about *exact equations* first, and how we solve them (see e.g. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx). Once you know about this, you can try to multiply the given ODE through by a certain function (an integrating factor) that will turn the DE into an exact equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M(x,y)=y$ and $N(x,y)=3+3x-y$. This is clearly not an exact equation, since $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$. However, one can make such an equation exact by introducing an integrating factor of the form $\mu(y)$. So, we require that $\mu(y)$ satisfy:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\mu(y)M(x,y))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu(y)N(x,y))$$
This means:
$$y\mu'(y)+\mu(y)=3\mu(y)$$
Solving this ODE gives the integrating factor $\mu(y)=y^2$. So, consider the following ODE instead:
$$y^3~dx+(3y^2+3xy^2-y^3)~dy=0 \tag{1}$$
Clearly, we now have:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y^3)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(3y^2+3xy^2-y^3)$$
So equation $(1)$ is exact, and is solvable by elementary methods.

Comment: Omg bless you! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\,dx}{\,dy}-\frac3y x=\frac{3-y}{y}.$$
Integrating factor $=\exp(-3\log y)=1/y^3.$

Solution: $\displaystyle x/y^3=\int (3-y)/y^4\,dy$